# Review pending edits when editing a documentation example

Tags: support, documentation

When attempting to editing an example with pending edits, we get notified about the fact that there are that there are pending drafts and also a possibility to view them.

Is there a way to quickly get to the corresponding review item from there?

Also, is there a way to quickly determine which of these drafts might actually conflict with our changes (i.e. modified the same example)?